# Dividing subnets with ipv6

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, iteration, ipv6

for example, i recieved from POST ip and mask:

```
$ip = 2001:db8::1428:55ab;
$mask = 48;
```

and i want divide this subnet, i choose for example mask and how many subnets i want, for example $mask = 50, subnets = 2

and my result is (tree in a table), like this:

```
ip                           mask         status
2001:db8::1428:55ab          48           divided
 - 2001:db8::??????          50           free
 - 2001:db8::??????          50           free
```

how can i do this? need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$mask` is actually the prefix-length. It is the number of bits that is 'fixed'. So a `/48` prefix length means that the first 48 bits are fixed and the last (128 - 48 = ) 80 bits are available to be used.

In IPv6 a LAN always gets a `/64`. This means that with a `/48` you get (64 - 48 = 16 bits. 2<sup>16</sup> = ) 65536 subnets.

IPv6 addresses and prefixes are written in hexadecimal. Each hexadecimal character is 4 bits. In IPv6 each group of numbers between `:` is 16 bits. Leading zeroes in each group can be omitted. So `2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001` is the same as `2001:db8:0:0:0:0:0:1`. The combination `::` means that in that spot are only zeroes. So that address can also be written as`2001:db8::1`.

The information you give is a little confusing. You specify `2001:db8::1428:55ab/48`. The problem is that you specify the last 32 bits of the IPv6 address (`1428:55ab`), while the mast specifies that those bits are not fixed. I will therefore use `2001:db8:1a2b::/48` as example.

Each increase in prefix length splits the previous prefix in two.

`2001:db8:1a2b::/48` can be split into:

- `2001:db8:1a2b::/49`
- `2001:db8:1a2b:8000::/49`

`2001:db8:1a2b::/49` can be split into:

- `2001:db8:1a2b::/50`
- `2001:db8:1a2b:4000::/50`

`2001:db8:1a2b:8000::/49` can be split into:

- `2001:db8:1a2b:8000::/50`
- `2001:db8:1a2b:c000::/50`

Etc.

You could write it as a tree (just showing a few branches, I don't want to fill the page with the full 65536 subnets):

- `2001:0db8:1a2b:0000::/48`

  - `2001:0db8:1a2b:0000::/49`
  - `2001:0db8:1a2b:8000::/49`

    - `2001:0db8:1a2b:8000::/50`

      - `2001:0db8:1a2b:8000::/51`
      - `2001:0db8:1a2b:a000::/51`

        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:a000::/52`

          - `2001:0db8:1a2b:a000::/53`
          - `2001:0db8:1a2b:a800::/53`
        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:b000::/52`

          - `2001:0db8:1a2b:b000::/53`
          - `2001:0db8:1a2b:b800::/53`
    - `2001:0db8:1a2b:c000:/50`
    - etc.

As you can see it's not that easy to read. It's easier if you subnet on multiples of 4 because then it matches the hexadecimal characters:

- `2001:0db8:1a2b:0000::/48`

  - `2001:0db8:1a2b:0000::/52`
  - `2001:0db8:1a2b:1000::/52`
  - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2000::/52`

    - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2000::/56`

      - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2000::/60`

        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2000::/64`
        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2001::/64`
        - ...
        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:200f::/64`
      - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2010::/60`

        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2010::/64`
        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:2011::/64`
        - ...
        - `2001:0db8:1a2b:201f::/64`
      - ...
      - `2001:0db8:1a2b:20f0::/60`
  - `2001:0db8:1a2b:3000::/52`

    - etc.

Comment: great explanation! thanks! Can you help me with another step, I received $_POST prefix-length and address, for example address = 2001:db8:1a2b::, prefix = 48, and i have edit form where i need to split this to subnets, a can choose prefix and count of subnets, how can do this in PHP?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to use `inet_pton()` to convert it to binary and then work with the bits from there. Then use `inet_ntop()` to convert it back to human-readable form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`cidrl6`**](https://github.com/emden-norfolk/cidrl) to split a */48* into four */50* subnets:

```
$ cidrl6 -s50 2001:db8::1428:55ab/48
2001:db8::/50
2001:db8:0:4000::/50
2001:db8:0:8000::/50
2001:db8:0:c000::/50
```

You could then read the output of this command into PHP as an array with something like [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```php
<?php

$ip = "2001:db8::1428:55ab";
$mask = 48; 
$subnet = 50; 

$subnets = []; 
exec("cidrl6 -s$subnet $ip/$mask", $subnets);
print_r($subnets);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2001:db8::/50
    [1] => 2001:db8:0:4000::/50
    [2] => 2001:db8:0:8000::/50
    [3] => 2001:db8:0:c000::/50
)
```